# hibernate many to many and java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a database and I'm trying to build an application around it. The problem is that I get Duplicate entry intermittently when I try to insert data into related tables.

For example, there is a Video entity and there is an Actor entity. There are many actors in each video, and each actor has acted in several films, so the connection is Many to many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "videos")
public class Video implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private int year;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "film_actors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")
    )
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Video video = (Video) o;

        return title != null ? title.equals(video.title) : video.title == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    //getters setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "actors")
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    private Set<Video> video = new HashSet<>();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Actor actor = (Actor) o;

        return name != null ? name.equals(actor.name) : actor.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to save a new Video entity in my service with an actor that is already in the actors table (with the same name), I get an error that it cannot be inserted, and this is rational, since the table has a uniqueness constraint on Actor.name column.

What behavior do I expect? I hope that hibernate will understand that there is already a unique value in the Actors table and will not try to insert an actor with the same name again, take its id and put it in the associated film_actor table.

This can be done ?

now I'm doing something like this to get around my problem, it doesn't seem like the right solution. Is this the only way?

```
 @Override
    public void save(Video video) throws SQLException {

        Set<Actor> actors = video.getActors();
        Set<Actor> mapped = new HashSet<>();
        for (Actor actor : actors) {
            Actor fromDb = actorRepository.findByName(actor.getName());
            if (fromDb != null) {
                mapped.add(fromDb);
            } else {
                mapped.add(actor);
            }
        }
        video.setActors(mapped);

        videoRepository.save(video);
    }
```

Comment: Hibernate will only understand uniqueness when the name in Actors table is annotated with @id but not sure if you can do that as its a legacy database.

Comment: Not legacy. He is understands.

Comment: Yes this is the only way if you are going to use a separate ID value that you aren’t passing in as the entity ID instead of the natural ID (name) that you are passing in (and around). Pick your ID wisely and the problem isn’t one

Comment: So, i should change id (from Long to String)?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate wouldn't understand if it's an existing entity if the `id` value is Zero and only `name` and other attributes are populated. If `id` value is zero, it will try to persist that data. So, when you are giving option to enter actors data, you should have something like drop down for existing actors, and data entry for new actors, so your request will have `id` for existing entities and zero for new entities. Now if you use `saveOrUpdate` instead of `save`, your problem should be solved. 
`saveOrUpdate` will make sure that existing entities are not saved again. Still to be sure, just check the documentation. If you are not sure about the implementation, your current additional method is fine too except it will cause performance overhead. 
 Use `show_sql` to actually see what's happening in the background

Comment: Save in spring works the same as saveOrUpdate. Only solution here is that you are saying to somehow query for the actor entity so it’s ID value is set and passed in, which will work for both save, saveOrUpdate and JPA operations like merge.